# how to solve ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

Tags: docker

I am trying to test how to add user

my docker info is:

```
% docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.7.1)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.2.1)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., 0.9.0)

Server:
 Containers: 94
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 94
 Images: 11
 Server Version: 20.10.11
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc version: v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.10.76-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 1.942GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: BNVF:OFMF:5YJE:SAGF:CVBA:IOGG:36BQ:G63I:J6YM:KWFY:P5CL:EX3U
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 48
  Goroutines: 46
  System Time: 2022-01-16T15:49:03.553220221Z
  EventsListeners: 3
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  http://hub-mirror.c.163.com/
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

my docker file is like:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER xueshan
RUN groupadd -r redis && useradd -r -g redis redis
USER redis
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

```
% docker build TEST -t testuser
[+] Building 0.1s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 163B                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                    0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [2/2] RUN groupadd -r redis && useradd -r -g redis redis                                                                 0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:74f15b450612cc59e37228be496e7c91f2f69b876073ec1803914932bd777eb2                                        0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/testuser                                                                                         0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
% docker run -it testuser
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "redis-server": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

from the output of buliding image, it seems that no error happened ...[?]
I am wondering how to solve this problem and run docker with user `redis`
or I have to add the path of this docker file as $path?

and I tried with `docker ps`

```
% docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

the result seems to show that no active container ... [?]

**what I expect to see is that after successfully building the image, if I run it with `docker run -it 'image'`, the user at the terminal should change to `redis`.**

*2021/1/20 1st Update*
[image: docker file]

[image: building results]

*2021/1/20 2nd Update*
[image: docker file]

[image: building procedure]

*2021/1/20 3rd Update*

[image]

[image]

*2021/1/20 4th Update*. **this is what I expect to see**

[image]

[image]

reference:

https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/beginners/dockerfile/user.html
https://programming.vip/docs/detailed-explanation-of-docker-dockerfile-instructions-and-practical-cases.html

Comment: You never actually install Redis in the image; you create a user named `redis` but don't actually install the server, and there is no `redis-server` binary to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't with adding the user. The problem is:

> starting container process caused: exec: "redis-server": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Meaning `redis-server` isn't in your `$PATH`

According to your `Dockerfile` you didn't install `redis`.

Try this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER xueshan
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y –no-install-recommends redis && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN groupadd -r redis && useradd -r -g redis redis
USER redis
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

Comment: but I did pull redis image via docker on my pc before ...                                  
                                                                                                                            
REPOSITORY    TAG                   IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
redis         latest                93f2223d3607   6 weeks ago    107MB

Comment: But you're not using the `redis` image in this case. See the `FROM` clause. The official redis image already has a user named redis (with uid 999) who runs the `redis-server` process. You need to update your original question with exactly what your goal is.

Comment: I read a tutorial and they offer a code example like ```RUN groupadd -r redis && useradd -r -g redis redis
USER redis
CMD ["redis-server"]``` trying to explain how to switch user. However, I do not know how to let it run without warning/mistake.

Comment: That's probably for a self-made image. You can use my example above. You still failed to explain what you're trying to do and why the official redis image doesn't meet your requirements. Please update your question to reflect that. This is not supposed to be a chat so please add all information required to the question.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to get how to switch user with this sample code (refer to the 2 linkes at the tail of description of this question) but I failed to let it run without error while I did not know what the root cause was.